# combobox always on top properites 

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, combobox

haw to make combobox always on top properites on vs 2008 c# .

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, I feel "Z-index" property should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Z-index, IE and combobox....was some time ago, but those three didn't play along so well...

Or maybe your problem can be fixed by setting the rendermode of the combobox to block?

More info, please?!